# Using sAjaxSource works, but setting the aaData myseld does not

Tags: javascript, datatables

When I'm using DataTables with sAjaxSource it works, but when doing the ajax upfront, and setting the aaData property I get error. Any ideas?

This method works:

```
   // This method works fine
$('#spiderData').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "spiderOrders.cshtml?GetOrders=true&pid=" + pid + "&itemid=" + itemId + "&signatur=" + signatur + "&orderid=" + orderid + "&type=signatur",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "BuildOrderId" },
        { "mDataProp": "description" },
        { "mDataProp": "BuildProductOrderId" },
        { "mDataProp": "state_desc" },
        { "mDataProp": "buildProductName" },
        { "mDataProp": "program" },
        { "mDataProp": "KP_BPO" },
        { "mDataProp": "WorkOrderId" },
        { "mDataProp": "title" },
        { "mDataProp": "state_desc" },
        { "mDataProp": "contractorName" },
        { "mDataProp": "TP" }
    ]
    });
```

But this does not:

```
     // This is not working, why????
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "spiderOrders.cshtml?GetOrders=true&pid=" + pid + "&itemid=" + itemId + "&signatur=" + signatur + "&orderid=" + orderid + "&type=signatur",
        data: "jalla",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#spiderData').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "BuildOrderId" },
                    { "mDataProp": "description" },
                    { "mDataProp": "BuildProductOrderId" },
                    { "mDataProp": "state_desc" },
                    { "mDataProp": "buildProductName" },
                    { "mDataProp": "program" },
                    { "mDataProp": "KP_BPO" },
                    { "mDataProp": "WorkOrderId" },
                    { "mDataProp": "title" },
                    { "mDataProp": "state_desc" },
                    { "mDataProp": "contractorName" },
                    { "mDataProp": "TP" }
                ]
            });

        }
    });
```

In case of the first example data returned has this format:

```
{ "aaData": [
{
    "BuildOrderId":"S2008-015758.001",
    "description":"Hordaland-Bergen-ALH4 - Leveranse av 2 Mb",
    "BuildProductOrderId":"S2008-015758.002", .....
```

And in the second example this format:

```
[{"BuildOrderId":"S2008-006891.001","description":"MXJP81, BERSTADHUSETMOB, HOR-00323","BuildProductOrderId":"S2008-006891.002", ....
```

Am I missing something, or formatting the response wrong (I've checked a few times now...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is it important to do it the second way? If you need access to all that .ajax has to offer (more flexibility in variables vs the default .getJSON) you can still do that with the fnServerData parameter.

That said, what's probably wrong with the second way is that you're trying to use "data" directly. It needs to be parsed first.

```
"aaData": $.parseJSON(data).aaData,
```

*disclaimer: I haven't tested this and prefer the fnServerData method*

Comment: Should be: "aaData": $.parseJSON(data).aaData,

Comment: Thanks, Itay! Updated.